# First subscriber to hot publisher doesn't get any elements, second subscriber consumes each element twice. Why?

Tags: java, project-reactor

Here's a basic demonstration of a hot publisher in Project Reactor

```java
    @Test
    void testSimpleFlux() {
        Flux<Integer> intFlux = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
                .publish()
                .autoConnect()
                .log();
        intFlux.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newParallel("Thread-one"))
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
        intFlux.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newParallel("Thread-two"))
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }
```

## What I expected:

The first subscriber consumes all the elements (it subscribed and triggered emission first), while the second subscriber consumes only *some* of the elements since it comes late for the party (for example, only 2, 3, 4, and 5)

## What actually happened:

The first subscriber got nothing, while the second subscriber consumed every integer twice

```
08:10:04.095 [Thread-one-1] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.1 -- onSubscribe(FluxPublish.PublishInner)
08:10:04.095 [Thread-two-2] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.1 -- onSubscribe(FluxPublish.PublishInner)
08:10:04.106 [Thread-two-2] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.1 -- request(unbounded)
08:10:04.106 [Thread-one-1] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.1 -- request(unbounded)
08:10:04.108 [Thread-two-2] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.1 -- onNext(1)
1
08:10:04.109 [Thread-two-2] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.1 -- onNext(1)
1
08:10:04.109 [Thread-two-2] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.1 -- onNext(2)
2
08:10:04.109 [Thread-two-2] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.1 -- onNext(2)
2
08:10:04.109 [Thread-two-2] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.1 -- onNext(3)
3
08:10:04.109 [Thread-two-2] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.1 -- onNext(3)
3
08:10:04.110 [Thread-two-2] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.1 -- onNext(4)
4
08:10:04.110 [Thread-two-2] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.1 -- onNext(4)
4
08:10:04.110 [Thread-two-2] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.1 -- onNext(5)
5
08:10:04.111 [Thread-two-2] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.1 -- onNext(5)
5
08:10:04.111 [Thread-two-2] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.1 -- onComplete()
08:10:04.112 [Thread-two-2] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.1 -- onComplete()
```

How could you explain it?